# How to get data from a server using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get  data from a server using a url means, i will hit a url then i will get a data from server which i will use to save it in a db. How to call a url to get data from it. What is the procedure or code to automatically call a url

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/request/request. It should do the trick

Comment: Thanks it is working